# Restore gmail account to Android

Tags: gmail, restore, motorola-droid

I just got a new Motorola Droid Turbo 2, Android 5.1.1 I have 2 gmail accounts & 1 just disappeared (it was there as of yesterday), altho I can access it from any computer. I have tried to add the acct by doing the obvious: "Add Account" on my gmail page, and "Add an Acct" in Android settings w/no luck. Both seem to be treating it like I'm trying to establish a new acct not an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Storing this for future reference and to help others.

#### **Summary**

- 2 (multiple) gmail accounts
- desktop computers fine
- android mobile phone

  - 1 gmail account accessible the other not
  - had removed google authenticator 4 months ago on previous mobile
- new mobile 1 month ago

  > everything syncing and accessible till recent google account password change

#### **Actions**

- tried cache apps deletes, reboot
- tried google resync
- then tried android mobile google account remove of non-accessable gmail account
- successfully installed google authenticator on mobile by switching to working google acount via desktop computer
- **then tried disable 2 step authentication**
- then tried changing google account via lastpass (wanted one common password for both google accounts) which failed
- **changed google account password successfully via google account.** Rebooted mobile. Waited 1/2 hour for servers synching.
  Now able to logon to both accounts on mobile.

#### **Notes**

- only using lastpass on desktop and not mobile device
- google server synching most likely much quicker than 30 minutes
- I have not tried individual google account passwords yet
- I have turned google account 2 step verification back on
- I have not setup google authenticator app yet